# Get folder name from path in batch file. Not resolving

Tags: windows, batch-file, directory, dos

I have this path: `C:\dev\app\tomcat\apache-tomcat-base` stored as the variable `copyFile` within a batch file.

I am using the following code to try and obtain `apache-tomcat-base` (the folder name) as a new variable `copyfolderName`

```
for /f "delims=" %%F in ("%copyFile%") do (
        set copyfolderName=%%~nxF
)
```

however `copyFolderName` is ending up empty.

Note: The loop is never being entered

Taken from this snippet:

```
:: Check if the file to be copied is a directory of file. If a directory define %isDirect%
IF exist "%copyFile%\" set isDirect=directory
:: Copy folder with all contents
IF defined isDirect (
    ::Get name of folder for the copyingDirectory folder
    for /f "delims=" %%F in ("%copyFile%") do (
        echo setting %%~nxF
        set copyfolderName=%%~nxF
    )
    echo BASE NAME: %copyfolderName%
)
```

BASE NAME prints nothing

Comment: `Note: The loop is never being entered`  ? But in the loop is the place where you get the folder name? Or there's something I'm missing...

Comment: as in . 
If i add an echo inside the for loop, it never gets called.

Comment: probably you need to add the whole code.The problem is not in the excerpt above.

Comment: it works for me, how do you know that copyfoldername is empty?

Comment: added larger snippet

Comment: So do you have `isDirect`  variable?

Comment: yes as   BASE NAME:  is printed.  setting %%~nxF never appears though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
....
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo BASE NAME: !copyfolderName!
endlocal
....
```

When the cmd parser reads a line or a block of lines (the code inside the parenthesis), all variable reads are replaced with the value inside the variable **before** starting to execute the code. If the execution of the code in the block changes the value of the variable, this value can not be seen from inside the same block, as the read operation on the variable does not exist, as it was replaced with the value in the variable.

To solve it, you need to enable delayed expansion, and, where needed, change the syntax from `%var%` to `!var!`, indicating to the parser that the read operation needs to be delayed until the execution of the command.

Comment: @npocmaka, i know how it is :-)  Usually i start typing and while doing it i end seeing how foxidrive posts the same or better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Adding setlocal enabledelayedexpansion will solve the issue (I used a test folder in the below code)-

```
:: Check if the file to be copied is a directory of file. If a directory define %isDirect%
@echo off
set "copyfile=c:\drivers\test folder"
IF exist "%copyFile%\" set isDirect=directory
:: Copy folder with all contents
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
IF %isDirect% equ directory (
    ::Get name of folder for the copyingDirectory folder
    for /f "delims=" %%F in ("%copyFile%") do (
        echo setting %%~nxF
        set copyfolderName=%%~nxF
    )
    echo BASE NAME: %copyfolderName%
)
```

Tested output -

```
D:\Scripts>draft.bat
setting test folder
BASE NAME: test folder
```

Cheer, G

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it that way, consider this:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
IF exist "!copyFile!" ( set isDirect=directory
    for /f %%F in ("!copyFile!") do (
        echo setting %%~nxF
        set copyfolderName=%%~nxF
    )
    echo BASE NAME: !copyfolderName!
)
```